# Error Post using HttpClient - An error occurred while sending the request at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

Tags: c#, httpclient

I'm trying to POST using httpclient but I always get this error
An error occurred while submitting the request at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

I tested localhost using Fiddler and it worked

SEND DATA METHOD

```
public async Task<int> PostMIIData(List<Alert> data)
{
      
          string uri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LinkPost"]

            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
            string j1 = "{\"data\":" + json + "}";

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders
                  .Accept
                  .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(uri, new StringContent(j1,                    Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

            string responseText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return 0 ;
}
```

RECEIVE DATA METHOD

```
    [WebMethod()]
    [HttpPost]

    public static void PostDataMII([FromBody] List<Alert> data)
    {
        SqlManager sql = new SqlManager();
        sql.PostMII(data);
    }
```

Comment: Please see this link as to how to capture a return value in your receive data method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65549885/how-to-get-int-value-from-asp-net-core-webapi